# Whats wrong with my Date Query?

Tags: mysql, extract, dateadd

Having a problem with the following Query. i have a device table which logs devices founds in an area, along with a venue_id and a date-timestamp. I'm trying to get all devices in a venue from a given day, month and year, however only devices found after 12pm on that day, and before 12pm the next day. I've tried this, which is the closest i've got.

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (mac) ) AS devices,

EXTRACT( DAY FROM DATE_ADD(date_time, INTERVAL 12 HOURS) ) AS day

FROM detected_devices
WHERE venue_id = 1

AND EXTRACT( MONTH FROM DATE_ADD(date_time, INTERVAL 12 HOURS) ) = 12

GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day ASC
```

This doesn't work, and gives me the following error.

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM detected_devices WHERE client_id = 11 AND venue_id = 1 AND EXTRACT( MONTH F' at line 2
```

Comment: You don't seem to be showing the correct query, the error message refers to a different one

Comment: Sorry, took client_id out the query. Error from the same query plus another WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need ['HOUR' instead of 'HOURS'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) as the unit.

Comment: Amazed that i missed that. Sometimes you just don't see whats right infront of you. Cheers!!